# Display suitable information on web page from database after user logs in

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP codes and a database.

1. User can register using roll number, password and semester. I do plan to provide department as well later.
2. Teacher can add subjects based on semester. They can add class tests based on subjects.
3. In my simplest case, I have been able to login and see all subjects and all tests on pages '`view_subjects.php`' and '`view_tests.php`' respectively using `SELECT * ..`
4. I want to include a simple modification. I want to be able to show subjects and tests based on semester user is in, i.e filter.
5. I have created views I, II, III, IV where view names are semesters and are based on `CREATE VIEW II AS SELECT * subjects WHERE semester='II';`
   And Views I, III, IV respectively. Edit- Realised that it is not necessary.
6. Based on views, I want to execute `SELECT * FROM [viewname]` on step 3. Eg: `SELECT * FROM [I] , SELECT * FROM [II], ... SELECT * FROM [IV]`
7. But the suitable statement out of the four has to be executed based on the user logging in.

**Is my approach correct?**

If so, how can I get the semester name after if he/she logs in
Otherwise, how should I approach this problem?

**Edit** My problem is to add a filter. I want users to see their subjects and tests based on the semesters they are in. Semester is an attribute of the student table along with roll_no and password.

Comment: For this, you need to associate each user to a semester and than you can write your sql statement using where with student as reference.

Comment: I really wouldn't bother with MySQL's views. They offer no advantage over a regular query.

Comment: @Strawberry I have realised that part. I can simply query using "select * from view_subjects where semester={SEMESTER OF THE USER LOGGED IN}". How do I get the semester after the user logs in? The semester is an attribute in the user table along with roll number (or username) and password.

Comment: view_subjects does sound like a view though

Comment: @Strawberry No, it isn't a view. My project is like this: Teachers can add subjects and tests. Students can login and appear tests. Till now, I have been able to do the part where students can login and view all subjects and all tests. I want to filter tests or subjects according to their semester. Student table has attributes roll_no, password and semester. So, after the student logs in, how do I get his semester from the Student table and necessarily get the subjects and tests. my problem is just that. To get the semester value after the user logs in and possibly store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this makes sense, Im not going to write code as i dont know what you are working with there, but for situation like this, Following will be the basic idea.

**Method one(i do not prefer this)**

1. Add a current_semester field in student table, where you store semester id. This is to be updated every time a student completes a semester.
2. before loading your information page, save the value of current_semester in a variable, and use something like, "SELECT * FROM [semester table] WHERE id = [current_semester]"

This will give you the current semester of his/her semester where ever you want but it will not save his semester history.

**Advised Method(using different table to save student's semester history)**

1. create new table "student_semester" with id, semester_id(foreign key from associated semester), student_id(foreign key from associated student), start_date and any other info that you may want.
2. simply get the latest record associated with that user which will be the current semester
3. this method will allow you to store semester history each student

Advise: Use Laravel, Eloquent makes this sort of work extremely easier.

Comment: Actually I don't need to do the feature which you are asking to :-D I am a beginner and I will try that later some time. For now, please provide me a solution of the problem which I asked.